# How to implement likeable collection in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have a collection for image uploading represented in following code:

```
Images = new FS.Collection('images', {
  stores:[new FS.Store.FileSystem('images', {path:"~/projectUploads"})]
});
```

I would like to have a custom 'like' button to make images I upload likeable. So how do I do that? I tried to make it with `socialize:likeable` package, but it doesn't seem to work for `FS.collection`, or may be I'm doing it wrong, I just put `LikeableModel` right before `FS.Collection` like this:

```
Images = new LikeableModel.FS.Collection('images', {
    stores:[new FS.Store.Filesystem('images', {path:"~/projectUploads"})]
});
```

Comment: how about some demo code?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I improved my question a little bit by providing sample code I tried